# Specific links not "clickable" on older iPhone/iPad

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, ios6

I'm testing a page on mobile devices and I noticed that three specific links are not working (they are not "clickable") on some iPhones/iPads.  My client spotted this on his iPhone and iPad, and so far I have only been able to replicate it on a test iPhone 4 with iOs 6.1.3.

The page is xxxxx and the three links that do not work are the < X > navigation at the top of the page.

I've tried checking for overlapping divs.  Couldn't spot that as the issue.  If it is a Safari/iOs issue that I can't fix through some code, that'd be helpful to know too.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Apologies- my browser autocorrected the word.  Fixed now.  Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This three elements are not selectable by touch because there's no real content inside of them. Set them as display: block; so they become block elements.

```
#arrowleftsmall a,
#arrowrightsmall a,
#thex2 a {
  display: block;
}
```